# Too many apache processes

Tags: process

I'm running a Centos 7.2 server with Apache version 2.4.6, with 6gb of ram and with Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3930K CPU @ 3.20GHz, 2 cores processor.

After I start apache webserver, with four wordpress sites, apache takes almost all of my ram memory and cpu, but it varies from time to time. Sometimes it takes around 1,5gb of ram and 40% cpu, but sometimes it takes all of my ram and 94% of cpu, and there are around 20 or even more of these processes :

/usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

Taking all of ram and cpu.
After all ram i taken , mysql server crashes.

This is my httpd.conf file :
 http://apaste.info/gg6

I have tried to limit processes by adding , :

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module> 

   StartServers 2
   MinSpareServers 2 
   MaxSpareServers 5 
   MaxClients 50
   MaxRequestsPerChild 0 

</IfModule>
```

But without of success,and prefork module is enabled.

[Processes image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjGUa.png)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your processor has 6 cores http://ark.intel.com/products/63697/Intel-Core-i7-3930K-Processor-12M-Cache-up-to-3_80-GHz

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `MaxMemFree` and `MaxRequestWorkers` directives?

[MaxMemFree](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#maxmemfree) sets ammount of memory in KBytes which will be availiable for each apache process without calling `free()` function.

[MaxRequestWorkers](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mpm_common.html#maxrequestworkers) sets ammount of simultaneous processes, other request will be queued till `ListenBacklog` is reached.